# How to Use Amplify Console as Reverse Proxy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, aws-amplify

Currently, I am working on an app that is running on AWS Cloud.

I use CloudFront + S3 to host my website, but I'm trying to switch the hosting service to Amplify Console. I'm also going to set a custom domain to my Amplify Console app.

At the same time, I am going to have a new CloudFront distribution as a CDN for images, and I want to make it available with the same domain as my Amplify Console app.

So, I assume that the possible way to achieve this is to have a reverse proxy, which forwards the requests to appropriate endpoints by request paths. (For example, If a request path starts with /img/, the request will be forwarded to the image CDN endpoint)

I am planning to use my Amplify Console as a reverse proxy, using the url rewrite feature. But when I made settings that forwards the specific request (like a request path that starts with /img/) to my CloudFront, I got a 403 error.

Do you guys come up with any solutions for this issue? If there's no way to solve this, I will consider trying API Gateway for a reverse proxy.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did

1. Created a static html webapp
2. Created a new hosted webapp (frontend) in AWS amplify
3. select the option - Deploy without GIT Provider
4. upload the static html webapp in the next step
5. After the application is up, go to App Settings > Rewrites & Redirects & create rules as mentioned in the blog: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/architecture/serving-content-using-fully-managed-reverse-proxy-architecture/

I created the rule as below
`source: /<*>  target: https://somewebsite/<*> type: 200 (Rewrite)`
Note: "<*>" if very important in both the source & target

Comment: I also did this. However, I'm finding that the 200 (Rewrite) does not preserve some `X-` headers arriving with the original request. Any help in getting those headers from the original request preserved in the amplify 200 (Rewrite)?